# Hash Enumerable methods: Inconsistent behavior when passing only one parameter

Tags: ruby, hash, enumerable

Ruby's enumerable methods for `Hash` expect 2 parameters, one for the key and one for the value:

`hash.each { |key, value| ... }`

However, I notice that the behavior is inconsistent among the enumerable methods when you only pass one parameter:

```
student_ages = {
"Jack" => 10,
"Jill" => 12,
}

student_ages.each { |single_param| puts "param: #{single_param}" }
student_ages.map { |single_param| puts "param: #{single_param}" }
student_ages.select { |single_param| puts "param: #{single_param}" }
student_ages.reject { |single_param| puts "param: #{single_param}" }

# results:

each...
param: ["Jack", 10]
param: ["Jill", 12]

map...
param: ["Jack", 10]
param: ["Jill", 12]

select...
param: Jack
param: Jill

reject...
param: Jack
param: Jill
```

As you can see, for `each` and `map`, the single parameter gets assigned to a `[key, value]` array, but for `select` and `reject`, the parameter is only the `key`.

Is there a particular reason for this behavior?  The docs don't seem to mention this at all; all of the examples given just assume that you are passing in two parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked Rubinius behavior and it is indeed consistent with CRuby. So looking at the Ruby implementation - it is indeed because [`#select` yields two values](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/4eec62a07d6b3cbdfee3c4ce0b6e6a18498641a4/kernel/common/hash.rb#L511):

```
yield(item.key, item.value)
```

while [`#each` yields an array with two values](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/4eec62a07d6b3cbdfee3c4ce0b6e6a18498641a4/kernel/common/hash.rb#L335):

```
yield [item.key, item.value]
```

---

Yielding two values to a block that expects one takes the first argument and ignores the second one:

```
def foo
  yield :bar, :baz
end

foo { |x| p x } # => :bar
```

Yielding an array will either get completely assigned if the block has one parameter or get unpacked and assigned to each individual value (as if you passed them one by one) if there are two or more parameters.

```
def foo
  yield [:bar, :baz]
end

foo { |x| p x } # => [:bar, :baz]
```

---

As for why they made that descision - there probably isn't any good reason behind it, it just wasn't expected people to call them with one argument.

Comment: Thank you.  This makes it very clear why the methods behave this way.  As for why they made this decision: If they didn't expect people to call them with one argument, why not just not allow it and throw an Argument Error?  To me, they should either do that or be consistent across all methods...

Comment: @dwenzel,blocks tend to be more permissive about their arguments. If more values are passed then needed - the remaining values are ignored. If less values are needed - the missing values are considered `nil`. The only way to verify that the block expects the exact amount of arguments (which is unidiomatic on itself) and raise an exception is to convert it to a proc and call [`Proc#arity`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Proc.html#method-i-arity). However, this comes with significant [performance hit](http://mudge.name/2011/01/26/passing-blocks-in-ruby-without-block.html), which is not something

Comment: @dwenzel, you would want from the most used methods in one of the most used classes.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that internally `map` is just `each` with `collect`.  Interesting they don't work quite the same way.

As to `each`...

The source code is below. It checks how many arguments you've passed into the block. If more than one it calls `each_pair_i_fast`, otherwise just `each_pair_i`.

```
static VALUE
rb_hash_each_pair(VALUE hash)
{
    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(hash, 0, 0, hash_enum_size);
    if (rb_block_arity() > 1)
    rb_hash_foreach(hash, each_pair_i_fast, 0);
    else
    rb_hash_foreach(hash, each_pair_i, 0);
    return hash;
}
```

`each_pair_i_fast` returns two distinct values:

```
each_pair_i_fast(VALUE key, VALUE value)
{
    rb_yield_values(2, key, value);
    return ST_CONTINUE;
}
```

`each_pair_i` does not:

```
each_pair_i(VALUE key, VALUE value)
{
    rb_yield(rb_assoc_new(key, value));
    return ST_CONTINUE;
}
```

`rb_assoc_new` returns a two element array (at least I'm assuming that is what `rb_ary_new3` does

```
rb_assoc_new(VALUE car, VALUE cdr)
{
    return rb_ary_new3(2, car, cdr);
}
```

`select` looks like this:

```
rb_hash_select(VALUE hash)
{
    VALUE result;

    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(hash, 0, 0, hash_enum_size);
    result = rb_hash_new();
    if (!RHASH_EMPTY_P(hash)) {
    rb_hash_foreach(hash, select_i, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and `select_i` looks like this:

```
select_i(VALUE key, VALUE value, VALUE result)
{
    if (RTEST(rb_yield_values(2, key, value))) {
    rb_hash_aset(result, key, value);
    }
    return ST_CONTINUE;
}
```

And I'm going to assume that `rb_hash_aset` returns two distinct arguments similar to `each_pair_i`.

Most important notice that `select`/etc doesn't check the argument arity at all.

Sources:

- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d5c5d5c778a0e8d61ab07669132dc18fb1a2e874/hash.c
- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/9f44b77a18d4d6099174c6044261eb1611a147ea/array.c